# Having trouble with stock prediction script in Python

Tags: python, stock

I recently found this script that you can find [here](https://github.com/Lucas-Kohorst/Python-Stock/), and I have tried it out, but it says `[TICKER] has not been predicted.` So, I dug into the code, and found a little code that helped me:

```
for i in stock_list:
        print("Number: " + str(number))
        try:
        predictData(i, 5)
        except:
            print("Stock: " + i + " was not predicted")
        number += 1
```

I then commented that out to see what was causing it to not predict it. This is what I got out of it:

```
Number: 0
AKS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finance.py", line 104, in <module>
    getStocks(200)
  File "finance.py", line 34, in getStocks
    predictData(i, 5)
  File "finance.py", line 86, in predictData
    X, Y, test_size=0.5)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Aha! So, the little piece of code that was being a b*tch was this:

```
    X = np.array(df.drop(['prediction'], 1))
    Y = np.array(df['prediction'])
    X = preprocessing.scale(X)
    X_prediction = X[-forecast_time:]
    X_train, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
        X, Y, test_size=0.5)
```

I think the reason that this was not working is because

```
 X_train, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
        X, Y, test_size=0.5)
```

was giving 4 outputs, but there were only 3 variables. I don't know what I should do here, because I tried to add another variable to that, but got this: `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`... 
*sigh*

Comment: Where is finance.py? I'm trying to find the code for model_selection.train_test_split

Comment: Oh, sorry, thats just what I called it. Head over to the Github link in the thingy and its the StockStart.py or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model_selection.train_test_split(...)` and `cross_validation.train_test_split(...)` return an even number of arrays (in fact, it is 2 * the original number of arrays). With that said, you're inputting an X and Y array so you should expect the output to contain 4 arrays. Try changing your code to read

```py
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.5)
```

If you said you get an error when you put in the 4th variable, can we see the traceback? I suspect it's not on the same line but I have no way to run the code right now so I can't do it myself

Comment: Sure. I can do that.

Comment: Yep, its working now. I don't know how you did it, but It does work! I'll pm you the stuff.

Comment: Nice job, by the way.